# JavaScriptDeserializer exception parsing JSON response

Tags: asp.net, json, deserialization

I am parsing a JSON response from Citrix' web services. The response looks like this

```
[{\"webinarKey\":123456,\"subject\":\"Subject\",\"description\":\"Webinar Description. \",\"organizerKey\":123456,\"times\":[{\"startTime\":\"2012-05-08T16:00:00Z\",\"endTime\":\"2012-05-08T17:00:00Z\"}],\"timeZone\":\"America/New_York\"}]
```

I manually edited that string to remove identifying information, so if there is a missing quote or anything it is unrelated.

I followed the example from this answer on SO, but still am encountering an error.

[Deserializing JSON result with Json & JavaScriptSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838811/deserializing-json-result-with-json-javascriptserializer)

```
public class Webinars {
    public string webinarKey;
    public string subject;
    public string description;
    public string organizerKey;
    public WebinarTimes[] times;
    public string timeZone;
}

public class WebinarTimes {
    public string startTime;
    public string endTime;
}

JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var foo = jss.Deserialize<Webinars>(JSON);
```

I receive the following error: `Type 'Web.Site.Webinars' is not supported for deserialization of an array.`

Comment: If I'm not wrong you need to use jss.Deserialize<IList<Webinars>>(JSON)

Comment: @ClaudioRedi - that certainly helped, resolved first error, now new error is `WebinarTimes is not supported for deserialization of an array.`

Comment: @ClaudioRedi - fixed, if you post as answer I will accept. Had to modify `Webinars` to include `WebinarTimes` as an array.

Comment: Posted as an answer. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `IList<Webinars>` instead of `Webinars`

```
var foo = jss.Deserialize<IList<Webinars>>(JSON);
```